# How many types of packing are present in solids?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Today when I come across packing in solids I encountered only two types of packing known as close packing -ccp and hcp.  I want to ask if there are 14 types of bravais lattices then should there not be 14 types of packing possible?  In short iwant to ask how many types of packing are present in solids?

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked it up first

Answer (score 0):

ccp and hcp are the two densest packings, but there are other packings such as fcc, bcc, and primitive. These relate to how atoms are organised with respect to the unit cell. But there can be different types of unit cell. For example, you can have an fcc arrangement with a cubic or orthorhombic unit cell. All of these possible combinations total 14 possible lattices. You can find an image for each one at [Wiki: Bravais lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice).